# How to merge two or more columns into one?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a streaming Dataframe that I want to calculate `min` and `avg` over some columns.

Instead of getting separate resulting columns of `min` and `avg` after applying the operations, I want to merge the min and average output into a single column.

The dataframe look like this:

```
+-----+-----+
|  1  |  2  |           
+-----+-----+-
|24   |  55 |
+-----+-----+
|20   |  51 |
+-----+-----+
```

I thought I'd use a Scala tuple for it, but that does not seem to work:

```
val res = List("1","2").map(name => (min(col(name)), avg(col(name))).as(s"result($name)"))
```

All code used:

```
val res = List("1","2").map(name => (min(col(name)),avg(col(name))).as(s"result($name)"))

val groupedByTimeWindowDF1 = processedDf.groupBy($"xyz", window($"timestamp", "60 seconds"))
  .agg(res.head, res.tail: _*)
```

I'm expecting the output after applying the `min` and `avg` mathematical opearations to be:

```
+-----------+-----------+
|  result(1)|  result(2)|           
+-----------+-----------+
|20 ,22     |  51,53    |
+-----------+-----------+
```

How I should write the expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is to merge the values of multiple columns together in a single column. For this you can use the [`array`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#array-org.apache.spark.sql.Column...-) function. In this case it would be:

```
val res = List("1","2").map(name => array(min(col(name)),avg(col(name))).as(s"result($name)"))
```

Which will give you :

```
+------------+------------+
|   result(1)|   result(2)|
+------------+------------+
|[20.0, 22.0]|[51.0, 53.0]|
+------------+------------+
```

Comment: Thanks , In addition how to merge column name with  DF  row. I want result [20.0,22.0,result(1)] in this format. how should be expr ?
val res = List("1","2").map(name => array(min(col(name)),avg(col(name))).as(s"result($name)"))

Comment: @shrikrishna: If I understand correctly you want to add the column name to the array? That seems very inconvenient to be honest, but you can add it with `lit(s"result$name")`.

Comment: @ Shaido its work for me. I need column name  for ForeachWriter  for further operation and DB sink class. is any better design?

Comment: @shrikrishna: I suspect there is but it depends on your actual situation, I would recommend asking a new question about it with more details.

Answer (score 2):

Use [struct](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) standard function:

> **struct(colName: String, colNames: String*): Column**
>
> **struct(cols: Column*): Column**
>
> Creates a new struct column that composes multiple input columns.

That gives you the values as well as the names (of the columns).

```
val res = List("1","2").map(name => 
  struct(min(col(name)), avg(col(name))) as s"result($name)")
  ^^^^^^ HERE
```

The power of `struct` can be seen when you want to reference one field in the struct and you can use the name (not index).

```
q.select("structCol.name")
```